# sort hbase table based on counter with billions of rows

Tags: hbase

I have been working on a crawler. List of urls are being stored in a hbase table, with a counter for reference count.

I have to sort the table to get top 1000 urls at any time to keep the crawler focused on high value urls.

One option is to use pig script with filters and scan hbase.
Other option is to maintain another table with reference count as key, managing and storing over head increases though.

Please suggest a better way of doing this.

Comment: Brother have you solved your problem. If yes then please share the solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to have a service that launches periodic map-reduces over the table to produce the top-n URLs in the database.

You then either query that service periodically or have it update a table with the current top URLs.